# Methods to send Logs and metrics of tomcat server to apache kafka

Tags: java, logging, apache-kafka, log4j, tomcat9

I am studying about apache kafka for past two weeks and I have managed to understand how kafka functions, kafka producer and consumer works. Now I want to design a small java program where I can send my apache tomcat 9 logs and metrics to kafka as it can be used for log aggregation purpose. I have searched how to do this, any method or tool I have to learn to design this and I came to know about Log4j.jar through which I can produce custom logs in apache tomcat but I don't know how to send this log to kafka? Please give some guidance regarding this on how to do this program if anyone done this work before.
Thank you.

Comment: Did you try with the Log4j 2.x [`KafkaAppender`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#KafkaAppender)?

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz Yes sir, But I got confusion where to use it on either tomcat side or kafka side so I didn't go deep on studying about that.

Comment: Log4j 2.x is an API to produce log messages, so you need to configure it on Tomcat/web applications side. If you want to send to Kafka also the logs generated by Tomcat itself (which uses JULI), you need to use the [Log4j App Server Integration](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-appserver/index.html).

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz Thanks sir, will look on it.

Answer (score 2):

As commented, you would use `KafkaAppender` on the application server-side to point at your Kafka brokers to send data to it; Kafka doesn't request data from your applications.

You can also write logs directly to disk, and use any combination of log-processors like Filebeat, Fluent-bit, Rsyslog, which all have Kafka-integrations.

Comment: ok sir, so I guess log-processors are used here for converting logs in a specific format like JSON right?

Comment: Not necessarily. You can make log4j output JSON on its own

Comment: Yes sir I understood now and I also have some doubt whether the same method applies for collecting logs and metrics of kafka server too?

Comment: Kafka uses log4j 1.x, which does not have a KafkaAppender, AFAIK, but you can use the same tools I mentioned for any process logs, yes. However, I would suggest not using one Kafka cluster for monitoring its own logs

Comment: Yes sir, log4j 1.x doesn't have any KafkaAppender and the think is I just want to get a single kafka broker logs and metrics through java programming, So as far as I understand from what you have said is, I have to create two kafka clusters and from one cluster I have to get its log and metrics through Kafka broker-configs and have to send those to another cluster for storing or processing. Is it the right method sir?

Comment: If the intention is to capture one cluster's downtime from its logs, then yes, you'd need a "standby"/monitor cluster, although, I'd suggest using Elasticsearch/Splunk for that data (from Filebeat & Metricbeat) instead of Kafka since you cannot easily search/aggregate log/metrics from Kafka alone

Comment: No sir, now I don't want to process the logs, I just want to collect a single kafka broker's logs and metrics, so does it requires a java program to perform this or is there any tool that can do the task? as far as I have searched that Jconsole can be used to view kafka's metrics and using log4j I can able to collect kafka broker's log and save it as a log file. So is this the good cause I don't want to complicate things now because I am very new this kafka server.

Comment: I never said process, I said capture (or collect). I gave you at least 4 tools that can do that. However, there is no point in collecting logs at all if you never intend to read (process) them